# How to create a home page containing many pieces in my headless project?

Tags: apostrophe-cms, apostrophe

In my project am using apostrophe as a headless cms. I have  front end in angular already designed . Also i have added many pieces for every collections i wanted to access in my project. Now the blockage is that,My home page is not a collection its actually a page having single banner, multiple testimonial pieces, multiple other images, etc...I want home as a page not a piece and inside that i need to add tabs such as banner,testimonial,... with its corresponding fields.i dont know if am clear but plz do help me to make it possible.Should i use apostrophe-pages for that?i dont want any pages to show in my backend right?since am using it as headless.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have created multiple piece types, which you are accessing using the REST APIs, but now you want to create home page content and get that with the API as well. You can definitely do that.

There's [documentation for this in the README](https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-headless/blob/2.10.3/README.md#working-with-pages). First make sure the REST APIs are turned on for pages:

```
modules: {

  'apostrophe-headless': {},

  'apostrophe-pages': {
    restApi: true
  }
}
```

Then `/api/v1/apostrophe-pages` gives you access to the page data, including various properties. It will includes the areas (and their widget data). But that area data can be tough to work with.

It can be easier to [access the rendered page or page fragments instead](https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-headless/blob/2.10.3/README.md#rendering-full-pages-and-page-fragments). I won't paste in all the documentation for that here, but you can get a (nearly) full page render (the part inside `[apos-refreshable]`) or definite "fragment" template files to retrieve instead.

Comment: Thankyou..am following the documentation u have mentioned